# Tronweb not listening events conistently

Tags: javascript, blockchain, tron, tronweb

I am creating a dapp on tron and using tronweb npm package. I am using its watch() to listen for events but it sometimes misses the event. Does anyone facing the same problem?
Is there any alternative for that?

Comment: More robust solution is to scan each block and view the events. When scanning for this blocks, make request to all available public node (as blocks get created really fast), use something like Promise.any, to process the first result you receive.